# Why does my loop not end?

Tags: java

This Method tests if the accountnumber is in the given array

```
public boolean containsAccount(int accountNumber) {
  int i;
  boolean ausgabe = false;
    for (i = 0; i < allAccounts.length; i++) {
        if (allAccounts[i].getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            ausgabe = true;
        }
        else if (i == length() - 1) {
            ausgabe = false;
        }
    }
    return ausgabe;
}
```

Expected to return true or false but it seems to be a neverending loop which retirns nothing.

Comment: You should print the `allAccount.length` to the console and then print `i` in every loop iteration. See if i becomes bigger than the account-length! The only thing that could fail is the `getAccountNumber()` or the `length()` method... the loop itself doesn't contain anything that would result in an endless loop!

Comment: Instead of looping through your array, you could use `return Arrays.asList(allAccounts).contains(accountNumber);`.

Comment: Your method looks fine (although it is very easy to include some simple optimizations). The only thing that comes to my mind is either a very big `allAccount` array (so it seems endless) or a infinite loop in your `getAccountNumber()` method.

Comment: we don't see the `allAccounts` variable or it's value here.

Comment: length() seems to be some function too - may be also a problem

Comment: The only possibility how this could end in an endless loop is if the size of the array `allAccounts` is changed in one of the mentioned methods. We'll have to see those 2 methods in order to help you (especially the `length()` method)!!!

Comment: @Wavemaster This only works if `allAccounts` isn't a primitive (which it probably isn't, but it must be made sure...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean containsAccount(int accountNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < allAccounts.length; i++) {
        if (allAccounts[i].getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // If the execution flow reaches this line, then that
    // means that the account 'id' does not exist in the array
    return false; 
}
```

Much cleaner, less variables & makes it easy to detect the real problem in your code. (Could be something with the `allAccounts` array, or the `accountNumber`)

Comment: This is actually much more readable and probably faster than the OP's version but it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @ParkerHalo you're technically right. I just wanted to point this out to the OP : this way if the code does not work, we will be certain that the `allAccounts.length` is changing value somewhere in the invoked methods inside. Plus the OP should update his post with the code of those methods, which he still didn't.